# SVN on Domain: How to release the trunk into a folder on the domain

Tags: svn, dns

Totally new to SVN, I apologize for noobishness. I've searched around to no avail on this issue (probably phrasing it incorrectly).

We have an svn set up on a networked Windows domain. Basically I want to be able to check out a file locally, modify, commit my changes into the trunk, then release the trunk into a folder on the domain.

It's the final step that I'm confused with.

I'm thinking it's something like:

svn copy  https://controller.company.local:8443/svnroot/javascript/trunk //controller/dummydirectory/

But obviously this doesn't work. I'm obviously missing something to do with how svn works, or the protocols in the command, or hopefully something as simple as a nonsensical file path.

Answer (score 0):

You could checkout the trunk to your network drive (do this once):

```
svn checkout https://controller.company.local:8443/svnroot/javascript/trunk //controller/dummydirectory/
```

And then update it whenever the trunk has been changed:

```
svn update //controller/dummydirectory
```

"update" will look for changes that were made on the trunk and merge them into your working copy on the network drive.

Alternatively you could also use svn export:

```
svn export https://controller.company.local:8443/svnroot/javascript/trunk //controller/dummydirectory/
```

This will only copy the files without any versioning information (i.e. without the .svn folder).

Hope this helps..